# multiple choice - save the result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown list and i want to create a multiple choice. 
In my situation result is saved like a  word "array", i dont know how to make it work.

form:

```
   <p>1.
<select name="sub1" size=14 multiple="multiple">
<option value="Русский язык" selected>Русский язык</option>
<option value="Математика">Математика</option>
<option value="Информатика">Информатика</option>
<option value="Обществознание">Обществознание</option>
<option value="Физика">Физика</option>
<option value="История">История</option>
<option value="Химия">Химия</option>
<option value="Литература">Литература</option>
<option value="Иностранный язык">Иностранный язык</option>
<option value="Биология">Биология</option>
<option value="Физическая культура">Физическая культура</option>
<option value="Творческий экзамен">Творческий экзамен</option>
<option value="Профессиональный экзамен">Профессиональный экзамен</option>
<option value="Собеседование">Собеседование</option>
</select></p>
  </p>
```

and script:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
  mysql_select_db("university") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $program = $_POST['program'];
  $code = $_POST['code'];
  $course = $_POST['course'];
  $form = $_POST['form'];
  $time = $_POST['time'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $accreditation = $_POST['accreditation'];
  $faculty = $_POST['faculty'];
  $department = $_POST['department'];
  $level = $_POST['level'];
  $type = $_POST['type'];
  $sub1 = $_POST['sub1'];
  $sub2 = $_POST['sub2'];
  $sub3 = $_POST['sub3'];
  $sub4 = $_POST['sub4'];
  $des = $_POST['des'];
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (program, code, course, form, time, price, accreditation, faculty, department, level, type, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, des) VALUES ('$program', '$code', '$course', '$form', '$time', '$price', '$accreditation', '$faculty', '$department', '$level', '$type', '$sub1', '$sub2', '$sub3', '$sub4', '$des')") or die(mysql_error());
var_dump($sub1);
?>
```

Comment: Does this code work? What's the error? What do you mean by saved like a word "array"?

Comment: do you want to insert each selected value in separate column? or in a single column like `val1,val2,val3...`

Comment: when im checking db in the result i see just word "array", and i need to see the values that i choosed

Comment: i want to save all the values in one column

Comment: then what sub2,sub3,sub4 are?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save all values in single column do it like this

```
$sub1 = "'".implode("','",$_POST["sub1"])."'";
echo "insert into table1(testcol) values($sub1)";
```

***output***

```
insert into table1(testcol) values('test','test1','test2')
```

and simply use `$sub1` in your query

Comment: what do u mean? how i can show u? i added new code in the descriptoin

Comment: first,can you tell me what are these sub2 sub3 sub4?

Comment: its nothing, its another dropdownlisps if i will make this one work? i will delete them

Answer (score 0):

When a form is submitted with a multiple select to a PHP script, the values are received as an array:

```
<select name="sub1" size=14 multiple="multiple">
```

becomes

```
sub1[] = 'selected choice 1';
sub1[] = 'selected choice 2';
sub1[] = 'selected choice 3';
```

To use them as a single string value, combine the array elements:

```
$finalVal = implode(',', $sub1);
```

Then use `$finalVal` in the SQL statement.

Comment: i added what u said, but it still doesn't work. i added
var_dump($array)  - it shows NULL
and i have a warning
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: Note that `name="sub1"` (not sub1[]). Try `$array = $_POST['sub1']; var_dump($array);`

Comment: in this case it saved only one last value
i updated my code in description